# Select email with only the name to send message

Tags: codeigniter-2

How can I select email with only the name to send message using Codeigniter?

```
function Validaremail($email) {   
    $query = $this->db->get('lists'); // Consulta Mysql para buscar en la tabla Usuario aquellos usuarios que coincidan con el mail y password ingresados en pantalla de login

    $query = $this->db->where('email', $email); // La consulta se efectúa mediante Active Record. Una manera alternativa, y en lenguaje más sencillo, de generar las consultas Sql.

    $query = $this->db->get('session');

    return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code from elislab codeigniter. It's standard sql query.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name FROM my_table LIMIT 1');

$row = $query->row();
echo $row->name;
```

[codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html)